# How to know inside MyButton::OnDraw that State is Pressed (Focused)

Tags: android

I am overriding the onDraw in my button class.

How do I know inside onDraw that the button was pressed ?

Comment: you should not extend Button class, you should extend Drawable class instead

Comment: any example? that would help

Comment: 1) extend Drawable 2) override isStatefull returning yes 3) override onStateChanged to get current state 4) implement draw method

Comment: i sent an answer yesterday (with detecting focused & pressed state), did it work?

Comment: I used the approach by @salman ayub

Comment: does it work for focused state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onDraw(..)` method of your Button, you can simply check for `this.isPressed()` 
This should return `true` when your button is pressed.

**EDIT:** 
You can also implement Touch Events in your `Button's subclass` :

`Example:`

```
public class tempButton extends Button {

public tempButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch(event.getAction())
     {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            //Button Pressed, Change the color of your Button here.

        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        break;

     }

    return true;
}

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, what are you exactly trying to accomplish ? Why are you trying to get State via onDraw Method ?

Comment: when focused I wish to change the color

Answer (score 0):

try this custom Drawable:

```
class SLD extends StateListDrawable {
    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] stateSet) {
        invalidateSelf();
        return super.onStateChange(stateSet);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int[] states = getState();
        Log.d(TAG, "draw " + StateSet.dump(states));
        boolean pressed = false;
        boolean focused = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            int state = states[i];
            if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
                pressed = true;
            }
            if (state == android.R.attr.state_focused) {
                focused = true;
            }
        }
        if (pressed) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xffff8800);
        } else
        if (focused) {
            canvas.drawColor(0xffff0000);
        } else
        canvas.drawColor(0xffaaaaaa);
    }
}
```

and test it with the following in onCreate:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("button #" + i);
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(new SLD());
    ll.addView(b);
}
setContentView(ll);
```